# Reasoning for inverse of Continuous Bijective function to be continuous

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity

I know this question has been asked already but I have following reasoning for inverse to be continuous, I don't know where I am going wrong.

Given that function $\mathbb F : \mathbb M \to \mathbb N$ between two metric spaces is continuous and bijection, now from definition of continuity in terms of convergent sequences, there should be same number of convergent sequences in set $\mathbb M $ and $\mathbb N$ (As it is bijection). If we think of inverse, then we can think in same scenario and can say that inverse is also continuous from convergent sequences. But there are some counter examples also, so where I am doing mistake ?

Comment: "from definition of continuity in terms of convergent sequences, there should be same number of convergent sequences in set M and N (As it is bijection)". It is simply not true in general that $f(x_n)\to_N f(x)\implies x_n\to_M x$. This is tantamout to saying that $f^{-1}$ is continuous (id est, your claim), which does not follow from the sequential definition of cotinuity.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $\mathbb F$ is continuous so it sends each convergent sequence from $\mathbb M$ to $\mathbb N$, it is bijection also, so there won't be more convergent sequences in codomian to which we can't find pair in domain.

Comment: In $99\%$ of the cases worth mentioning, the number of convergent sequences is at least $\beth_1$ (where $\beth_1=\text{cardinality of }\Bbb R$). So quantitative reasonings are quite pointless.

Comment: I realized that there is not bijection between convergent sequences, as there can be more convergent sequences possible in codomain.